# Java Game | Graphics2D realtime image blend mode

Tags: java, graphics, filter, jframe, imagefilter

I'm writing a little java game wherein i'd like to display a crumpled paper texture with the 'overlay' blend mode over the frame. The way my drawing system works is that it draws everything into a bufferedimage and then scales that to fit the frame appropriately with respect to aspect ratios. Is there any way to take this bufferedimage and very quickly overlay the paper texture on it? I'm pretty far into the project so I can't feasible change too much of the drawing system or switch to a game library. I was doing this manually with pixel-by-pixel processing, but that drops the framerate of the game massively. A big thanks to anyone that can help me!

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26746732/how-to-blend-two-image/26746827#26746827) and also like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26961190/can-i-have-image-alpha-fade-from-left-to-right-in-java/26962173#26962173) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969071/prevent-drawing-over-the-same-area-of-a-graphics2d/14971938#14971938) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342607/how-to-add-a-color-layer-to-the-image-in-paintcomponent-method/32342711#32342711)?

Comment: You might also like to have a look at [Compositing Graphics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/compositing.html)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I can't help but feel a bit stupid. I always research stuff like this thouroughly before posting (I've been at this for about a week!) I must've been looking for the wrong terms or something. Thanks a lot! If you post an answer I'll accept it as correct.